# Text in TextView: Color and Transparency using HTML

Tags: android, html, colors, textview, opacity

I'm trying to write text in `Textview` in white with an opacity of 75%, but I get the text in black, even though it works fine when I test it in an HTML page. Why this is happening?

**Code:**

```
String text = "<span style=\"color: #ffffff; opacity: 0.75;\">Text </span>";
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: see `ForegroundColorSpan` docs

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this

```
String text = "<span >Text </span>";
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));   
myTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
myTextView.setAlpha(Float.parseFloat("0.75"));
```

Comment: Actually I want to set different colors and opacities